# C To MIPS - translate a simple code

Tags: c, mips

```
int i;
void set_array(int num) {
    for (i=0; i<10;i++) {
        A[i] = compare(num,i);
    }
}

int compare (int a, int b) {
    if ((a-b) >= 0)
        return 1;
    else return 0
}
```

Getting some problems here.

My major problem is: how can you insert the compare(num,i) to A[i]?

By the way, I'm totally beginner in this, so sorry if it seems too easy to be asked.

Comment: I tried to format your code, but it's not valid so I don't want to mess with it. Try to get the `{` and `}` to match up, and make sure you have `;` where you need it. Most people indent their code so you can easily see where blocks (`{}`) end.

Answer (score 1):

In C you cannot "insert" values. First, you had to declare the [global] table A with either

```
int A[10];
```

assuming 10 is the size, based on `for` loop limit, or

```
int *A;
```

then somewhere else in code:

```
A = malloc (10 * sizeof *A);
```

so you will have a space allocated for 10 elements. Then you can set w a value of each element (like you do with `compare()` assignment).

Answer (score 1):

This is a multi-step process. The first part is passing the arguments to compare and calling it. When compare is done, it will return a value. It is this return value that you will store in A[i].

You can think of it as:

```
int temp = compare(num,i);
A[i] = temp;
```

Where temp is nothing more than $v0 (the return value).

The memory location where A[i] is the address of A + i * the size of an element of A. For this answer since you didn't really specify what is the type of A, I will assume it's an int array. Furthermore I am also assuming an int is 4-bytes (or a word) on your MIPS machine.

With this in mind, A[0] is the address of A + 0. A[1] is the address of A + 4. A[2] is the address of A + 8. And so forth.

A rough outline would be:

```
set_array:
    # save $ra to stack
    la      $s1, A         # assuming $s1 isn't used for anything
    # loop code starts here
                           # A[i] = compare(num,i);
    move    $a0, $a0       # num (Here for completeness, it does nothing)
    move    $a1, $s0       # I am just assuming variable 'i' is in $s0
    jal     compare        # call compare
    sw      $v0, 0($s1)    # store the return value in A+4*i
    addiu   $s1, $s1, 4    # inc it by 4, for the next element
    # i = i + 1
    # jump back up
    # restore $ra
    jr      $ra

# ...

compare:
    # code to compare and
    # return 1 or 0 in $v0
    jr      $ra
```